# Randomizing with Irvine32

Tags: assembly, random, x86, masm, irvine32

Program to randomize numbers 1-53 without repetition.

Can't get the `Check` loop to work, but I know that's the problem because it works without it, but I need it so I don't get repetition, and also how do you sort the numbers in order?

```
Include Irvine32.inc

.data   
   a dword 1
   b dword 53
   delta dword ?
   blank byte " ",0
   array dword 52 dup(0)
   lenarray = LengthOF array

  .code
    main PROC
    call randomize
    mov eax,b
    sub eax,a
    inc eax
    mov delta,eax
    mov esi,offset array
    mov edx,offset blank
mov ecx, lenarray

xxx:
push ecx
push esi    
bk: mov eax,delta
    call randomrange
    add eax,a
    mov esi,0    
    mov ecx,lenarray

Check:
 cmp eax,[esi]
 je bk                          ;if duplicate 
 add esi,4
 loop Check

 pop esi
 pop ecx
 call writedec
 call writestring
 mov [esi],eax
 add esi,4

 loop xxx
```

Comment: You're doing `mov esi,0` and then `mov eax,[esi]`. I'm guessing that's not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a random selection problem, you could pose this as one where you have a table of numbers that are psudo-randomly exchanged to provide you with the shuffling effect you require.

Fill the table with each number you need, and then using the number generator, select pairs of numbers in the table, and exchange them. This way, you can select how many items to change, and it ensures that no duplicates exist as no new numbers are created.